# LibGDX Lights and Shadows for my 2D TiledMap Game (like Terraria/Starbound)

Tags: 2d, libgdx, lighting, tilemap

Im currently working on my Terraria-Clone. After I have finished generating the world, I would like to add light and shadow to my game. For example, it would be light in the Upperworld during the day, but dark at night. In the Underworld (Mines/Caves) it is dark as well, but there are supposed to be blocks like torches, which radiate a light aura. At the moment I don't have anything yet, because I don't know how to start with this topic. That is why I am here now. Does anyone have any suggestions what I could do?

Here a Picture of my Game:
[image]

How I want it to look:
[image]

I hope you can help me.
Have a great day!

Comment: You might be interested in [Minecraft-Style Voxel Sunlight Algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/170011/39518) — the same logic would work in 2D.

Comment: I dont really understand how can I add this system to my project.

Comment: Can you describe where you've gotten stuck? The more detail you can share about your problem or point of confusion, the better we can target answers to help you overcome it.

Comment: Where am I stuck? I've been reading through the post and I haven't really understood anything. I think you mean in the post, they add a kind of of shadow from the sunlight behind blocks. I don't have a plan how to put that into my project.